# System Collection Array List

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to add data into a Combobox.

I have a userform that is used on two sheets. It creates a list of addresses. Depending on the active sheet, the address list is created from one of two sheets.

If the active sheet name = SCHECK.name then I use `System.Collection.ArrayList` to create the list of unique sorted values from sheet WIR, that is added to the Combobox.

If the active sheet is S20FA, then I create the list from CAL. I would like to use the System Collection, to create this as it is much faster than the solution I have creating an array, then looping over the array and adding to the Combobox.

The problem is, how to perform the checks that I need with `System.Collection.ArrayList`, before the address is added into the array.

Along with this, is it possible to use `System.Collection.ArrayList` to create a multi-dimensional array fo use with multi-column Comboboxes?

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
Dim myArrayList As Object 
Dim i, lastRow As Long 
Dim address() As String 
Dim number_address As Integer 
Dim cell As Range 
Dim addressList, addressItem

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call wb.defineCols 
Call wb.defineSheets

If ActiveSheet.Name = wb.SCHECK.Name Then
    If wb.WIR.FilterMode = True Then wb.WIR.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    lastRow = wb.WIR.cells(Rows.count, wb.COL_Address_code).End(xlUp).Row

    Set myArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    addressList = wb.WIR.Range(wb.WIR.cells(3, wb.COL_Address_code), wb.WIR.cells(lastRow, wb.COL_Address_code))

    With myArrayList
        For Each addressItem In addressList
            If Not .Contains(addressItem) Then .add addressItem
        Next
        .Sort
        If .count Then Me.address_combo.List = Application.Transpose(myArrayList.toarray())
    End With
    myArrayList.Clear
    Set myArrayList = Nothing
 ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = wb.S20FA.Name Then
    If wb.CAL.FilterMode = True Then wb.CAL.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    lastRow = wb.CAL.cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set cellRange = wb.CAL.Range("A8:A" & lastRow)
    DoEvents
    number_address = 0
    For Each cell In cellRange
        number_address = number_address + 1
        ReDim Preserve address(number_address - 1)
            If IsError(Application.match(cell, address, False)) Then

                '''' Test cells

                If wb.CAL.Range("G" & cell.Row) <> "" Then
                    If IsError(wb.CAL.Range("K" & cell.Row).value) = False Then
                        If wb.CAL.Range("K" & cell.Row).value <> "" And wb.CAL.Range("K" & cell.Row).value <> 0 Then
                            If (wb.CAL.Range("Q" & cell.Row).value <> "" And wb.CAL.Range("Q" & cell.Row).value <> 0) Or _
                               (wb.CAL.Range("W" & cell.Row).value <> "" And wb.CAL.Range("W" & cell.Row).value <> 0) Then
                                address(number_address - 1) = wb.CAL.Range("A" & cell.Row).value
                            Else
                                number_address = number_address - 1
                            End If
                        Else
                            number_address = number_address - 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    number_address = number_address - 1
                End If
            Else
                number_address = number_address - 1
            End If
    Next cell

    DoEvents
    For i = 0 To UBound(address)
        If address(i) <> "" Then
            address_combo.AddItem address(i)
        End If
    Next i 
 End If 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: You can add an array directly to a combobox by using ComboBox.List = MyArray()

Comment: @JiminyCricket Thanks for the response, although it doesn't reduce the speed by that much, I speed tested it and it took about 5 seconds to run looping over about 1000 rows, with the loop at the end, changing it to list had little effect to the time. which isn't so bad, but this document is used on a Citrix connection, which doubles if not triples the time to complete tasks. Whereas the system.collection.arraylist took 0.01 second to complete with a dataset of over 20000 rows, which is why I would like to be able to use that solution. Thanks

Comment: Are you bound to use `System.Collection.ArrayList`? It is really not the best solution for what you are trying to achieve. And that explains why your code is slow.

Comment: @A.S.H Hi, I am not bound to using System.Collection.ArrayList, but where I have used it, it was the fastest solution I found, along taking between 0.01 - 0.09 seconds to complete, evaluating over 20000 rows. It is the second array list that is taking the time, if I could get that down the similar speeds as the Collection.ArrayList that would be perfect. Thanks

Comment: Hi :). I see. So in the case `S20FA` you are using a normal VBA array. Problem is you are resizing it with `Redim` at each new element, leading to a lot of reallocations and relocations. This is indeed an expensive operation and needs to be optimized. I can propose a solution, but I have one more question: why in the case of `S20FA` you allow duplicate values, while you dont allow such duplicates in the case of `SCHECK`?

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you, that would be much appreciated! I am testing for duplicates in 'S20FA' i am using 'If IsError(Application.match(cell, address, False)) Then' to test if the address already exists within the array. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to avoid duplicates, better use a data structure that is designed to handle duplicates. `Scripting.Dictionary` is an excellent tool for this kind of applications; it denies duplicate keys so it will have a clean and unique list in its `.keys` array.

Below is a rewrite of the code using the dictionary data structure. Try it to see if it improves the speed. Note that the list is not sorted, but if speed is improved but we still needs sorting, we can add a sorting routine later.

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim dict As Object ' <-- changed the name to correspond to the dictionary
Dim i, lastRow As Long
Dim address() As String
Dim number_address As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim addressList, addressItem

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call wb.defineCols
Call wb.defineSheets

If ActiveSheet.Name = wb.SCHECK.Name Then
    If wb.WIR.FilterMode Then wb.WIR.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    lastRow = wb.WIR.Cells(Rows.Count, wb.COL_Address_code).End(xlUp).Row

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' <--
    addressList = wb.WIR.Range(wb.WIR.Cells(3, wb.COL_Address_code), wb.WIR.Cells(lastRow, wb.COL_Address_code))

    For Each addressItem In addressList
        If Not dict.Exists(addressItem.Value) Then dict.Add addressItem.Value, addressItem.Value
    Next
    If dict.Count > 0 Then Me.address_combo.List = Application.Transpose(dict.toarray())
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = wb.S20FA.Name Then
    If wb.CAL.FilterMode = True Then wb.CAL.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    lastRow = wb.CAL.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set cellRange = wb.CAL.Range("A8:A" & lastRow)
    DoEvents
    number_address = 0
    For Each cell In cellRange
        If Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) And _
            wb.CAL.Range("G" & cell.Row) <> "" And _
            Not IsError(wb.CAL.Range("K" & cell.Row).Value) And _
            wb.CAL.Range("K" & cell.Row).Value <> "" And wb.CAL.Range("K" & cell.Row).Value <> 0 And _
            ((wb.CAL.Range("Q" & cell.Row).Value <> "" And wb.CAL.Range("Q" & cell.Row).Value <> 0) Or _
             (wb.CAL.Range("W" & cell.Row).Value <> "" And wb.CAL.Range("W" & cell.Row).Value <> 0)) Then

             dict.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    DoEvents
    address_combo.List = dict.Items
 End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Hi, I couldn't get the dict to work, but I managed to work a solution using collection.arraylist. I have posted my answer. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You had me at Scripting.Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution that I have put together with some help from A.S.H suggestions.

I have kept the use of the original `System.Collection.ArrayList`, and am now using it in both instances.

Rather than looping over the sheet and performing my checks for the second requirement, I am now copying the entire range into memory and checking it there.

With this method, I am now achieving speeds of 0.03 seconds to complete rather than a few seconds previously.

If you can notice any mistakes or improvements, then please leave me a comment, I am always willing to try new solutions.

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim myArrayList As Object: Set myArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim i, lastRow As Long
Dim address() As String
Dim number_address As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim addressList, addressItem

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call wb.defineCols
Call wb.defineSheets

If ActiveSheet.Name = wb.PCHECK.Name Then
    If wb.WIR.FilterMode = True Then wb.WIR.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    lastRow = wb.WIR.cells(Rows.count, wb.COL_Address_code).End(xlUp).Row
    addressList = wb.WIR.Range(wb.WIR.cells(3, wb.COL_Address_code), wb.WIR.cells(lastRow, wb.COL_Address_code))
    With myArrayList
        For Each addressItem In addressList
            If Not .Contains(addressItem) Then .add addressItem
        Next
        .Sort
        If .count > 0 Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(myArrayList.toarray())
    End With
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = wb.S20FA.Name Then
    If wb.CAL.FilterMode = True Then wb.CAL.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    lastRow = wb.CAL.cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    addressList = wb.CAL.Range("A8:W" & lastRow).value
    With myArrayList
        For i = LBound(addressList) To UBound(addressList, 1)
            If Not .Contains(addressList(i, 1)) Then
                If addressList(i, 7) <> "" Then
                    If Not IsError(addressList(i, 11)) And addressList(i, 11) <> "" And addressList(i, 11) <> 0 Then
                        If (addressList(i, 18) <> "" And addressList(i, 18) <> 0) Then
                            .add addressList(i, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        .Sort
        If .count > 0 Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(myArrayList.toarray())
    End With
End If

myArrayList.Clear
Set myArrayList = Nothing
```